# Get all existing pointers to an object

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Is it possible to get a list of pointer to a pointers to an objective c object.

something like

```
id **pointers(id object, int *out_count)
```

Pretty crazy, huh? =)

Comment: you're right... its crazy..!!

Comment: You might get better answers if you tell us what you are trying to do. In this form I think the answer is *no*, at least without some support on the compiler side and without scanning the whole process memory (and filtering the false positives). BTW, why does the function return a pointer to `id`? The `id` type is usually used directly and I don’t see the point of returning an object from a counting function.

Comment: @zoul: "id *" is the type of a pointer to a C array of id's, so the function prototype makes sense...

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn’t realize he’s also after the pointers themselves.

Comment: @CRD: it doesn't make sense.  All the elements of the array would be the same, namely the id that you passed in.  You need an array of *pointers* to `id`s i.e. `id**`

Comment: your right! first variant whas id** but then i changed it for no reasons ) description of function is ok!

Comment: there is no real need for this ) i'm just curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. If such a thing were generally possible, then writing a precise garbage collector would be rather simple:

```
int count;
pointers(obj, &count);
if (count == 0) {
    free(obj);
}
```

Since the objective-c garbage collector has to chase pointers from roots, control the allocator, and scan the stack conservatively to achieve something like this, I think it's reasonable to assume that you'd need to do the same.

It might be possible to leverage the garbage collector's implementation of this, though, if running in GC mode. Not a good idea, not simple, and won't work on iOS, but maybe possible. libauto is open source after all.

Comment: The garbage collector uses compiler support to count the number of (heap) pointers pointing to some object. It only really counts stack and register pointers. But the leaks tool does something like that (scanning the whole heap for pointers). So it might be worth to look into that.

Comment: Actualy that is what ARC does. It holds object in memory while there is at least one pointer.

Comment: @Denis Mikhaylov: Both ARC and the garbage collector depend upon the compiler to count references to objects.

Comment: This hypothetical garbage collector wouldn't collect cycles.