# how to get all strong references to an object in LLDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, debugging, lldb

How to get all strong references to an object (identified by address) in LLDB?
I tried to use ptr_refs (as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310636/how-do-i-read-references-given-by-ptr-refs-in-ios)) but it contains too many, which makes me think not all of them are strong references (or existing ones) because I called retainCount and returns only 1.

Comment: Memgraph can do this too, but it takes too long for large app. So, just wonder if there is a lightweight way to get it.

Comment: @grubbyfan can you fix your link ?

Comment: @zeytin sorry done.

Comment: @matt how is it done in instruments?

Comment: @matt does it also give the referencing pointers or just the count?